# how can I display json data dynamically in Pie Chart in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How can I display json data dynamically in Pie Chart in Reactjs?

My `PieChart` class below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
   labels: [
    'Red',
    'Green',
    'Yellow'
   ],
   datasets: [{
      data: [300, 50, 100],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#FF6384',
        '#36A2EB',
        '#FFCE56'
   ],
   hoverBackgroundColor: [
     '#FF6384',
     '#36A2EB',
     '#FFCE56'
   ]
 }]
};

export default class PieChart extends Component {

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h2>PieChart</h2>
         <Pie height="100px" data={data} />
       </div>
     );
  }

}
```

Comment: Since `data` is a prop, whenever it changes your pie chart will be re-rendered. So you can just set the prop as part of `state` and get your JSON data.

Comment: How do you intend to get your JSON data?

Comment: In the above code I have hard Coded that, so I want to fetch it from Json file  and display it in the Pie Chart..

Comment: So your problem is mostly how to read the JSON data? Do you have that data somewhere already?

Comment: Ya i have one reducer file, in that i wrote json file..

Comment: In the above example I have added data 300, 50, 100 but I want to display the data that is coming from json file.

Comment: I haven't answered yet because you still haven't made clear what your problem is. You say you want to display the data that "is coming from" a JSON file. Do you want to _read_ the JSON file and you do not know how to do that? Or is the problem how to _display_ the data?

Comment: yep.. I want the json data like how many students got 1st class, 2nd class, juss pass and failed students info in to the Pie Chart dynamically.. if any changes made in the json file, it should reflect in the Pie Chart...

Comment: ooooooh, now I get it. So the issue is creating a data binding between the file and the pie chart props, isn't it?

Comment: yep. plz help me

Comment: Is your code working with static JSON object?

Comment: ya its working with static JSON object.. As you can see in above code I have added static number 300, 50, 100 in the data.